# Javascript faling to change span

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

The following javascript has stoped working and I dont no why I have it in my ready function to calculate all my textboxes that are prefxied in the css class with income some it seems to have broken again. I load default values via the text method so I am wondering if this is what is braking it!

If you look at my css class tag i have the value incomeSum there

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

        calculateSum();


$(".incomeSum").each(function () {

            $(this).keyup(function () {
                  calculateSum();

            });
        });
```

The above just calls the below function

```
 function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".incomeSum").each(function () {

            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }


        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        alert("Do i get to the span element!" + sum.toFixed(2));
        $("#sumTotalIncome").html(sum.toFixed(2));


    }
```

This is the code for the textbox there is about fifty on the control I put an aleart dialog there to see that it was indead firing and it is its just not written out the total to the label

```
 <div class="col-md-5 sidestight-left sidesthin-right">
   <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="WAGES_NET_CIC"  MaskSettings-AllowMouseWheel="false"   ClientIDMode="Static" MaskSettings-Mask="<0..999999999>.<00..99>" MaskSettings-PromptChar=" " ValidationSettings-Display="Dynamic" Native="True" CssClass="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid incomeSum" runat="server">
<MaskSettings Mask="<0..999999999>.<00..99>" PromptChar="" />
  </dx:ASPxTextBox>  </div>
```

The total label

```
<label class="total-bar-income total-bar-right">
  <span id="sumTotalIncome">0</span>
</label>
```

I have created a js fiddle here to see if someone can help me out

https://jsfiddle.net/gdzdknn0/

**Edit 1**
Ok So I am a bit futher but I have another error in my code and its stoping the above functions to work I want to go out to the spans of each section and do a figure on them but when i include this function it brakes the key up

```
function caclulateBalance() {
    incomescic = +$('#sumTotalIncome').text();
    expensecic = +$('#expendureTotalSum').text();
    reducible = +$('#reducibleSumTotal').text();
    incomes = +$('#totalsIncomeiande').text();
    expenses = +$('#totalexpensessum').text();


    $('#totalbalancesum').text((incomes - expenses).toFixed(2));
    $('#lblTotalcicSum').text(incomescic - (expensecic + reducible)).toFixed(2);

       }
```

Comment: Check the console. Your fiddle has several errors, not least of all you added a plain text sentence to the middle of the code. If you fix those problems, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gdzdknn0/1/

Comment: Hi Sorry yes that was just a typo mistake  what was the other error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gdzdknn0/3/ in here it is working. I added jquery external resource

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you can you mark as an answer however I am having trouble when i set a default value through the text method its not updating the totals ? https://jsfiddle.net/gdzdknn0/4/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you have a look at my edit i am a bit futher thanks just a balance calcualtion is braking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery. Fix your code typos, and include this snippet in your `<head>`, and you should be fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: that was indead why the jsfiddle was not working but not my full solution thanks for the input though